# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'r' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, function

I'm having an issue with variable and function. Here is a simple code:

```
r = 0
list = ['apple','lime','orange']
def list_list(x):
    for i in x:
        r +=1
        print r
list_list(list)
```

### Error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'r' referenced before assignment
```

I know it must be something simple. I started to do my script using functions instead straight code.

Comment: What is this function supposed to do? Your error is that r is global (not local) but I can't tell you how to fix it without knowing the intended behavior of the program.

Comment: There are probably 100 questions on SO about this. Ever tried google?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should rewrite your function to take `r` as an argument if you want to define it outside of your function:

```
def my_func(some_list, r=0):
    # do some stuff
```

Basically, you have a problem with scope. If you need r outside of the function, just return it's value in a tuple:

```
def my_func(some_list, r=0):
    # do some stuff

    return new_list, r

my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
different_list, my_outside_r = my_func(some_list, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `r` within the function isn't the same as the one outside the function, so it hasn't been set yet.

Answer (score 1):

You shoudld put `r = 0` inside the function. But if you want the length of the list just use `len(list)`

Also try to avoid naming variables same as builtin names like list.